# Function returns different datetime value in different Android version

Tags: java, android, datetime

I wrote the following function in Java to convert datetime to int. The int value is same as "new TimeSpan(dateTime.Value.Date.Ticks).Days" in .Net.

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public static long DateToInt(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date startDate = null;
    Date presentDate = null;

    try {
        startDate = dfDate.parse("01/01/1900");
        presentDate = dfDate.parse(date);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long diff = presentDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    diffDays = diffDays + 693595;

    return diffDays;
}
```

This function works fine in Android 19 but on Android 23 it returns different value.
For example in Android 19, if I pass the parameter "02/08/2016", on Android 19 this function returns 736177 and on Android 23 this function returns 736176.

Please help me to get same value on all  Android versions.

Comment: 1 Day out, are you sure it isn't a time difference on the devices?

Comment: I set GMT+6 on both devices but still facing the same error.

Comment: Java datetime isn't really that reliable to begin with. Maybe JodaTime would help

Comment: Does this happen on different devices  or is this related to the android version

Comment: Try the `SimpleDateFormat` with a fixed `Locale`.

Comment: This happens on different devices @Raghunandan

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
If I pass "08/02/2016", the line

```
long diff = presentDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
```

returns different value. On Android 19, it returns 3679084800000 and on Android 23 it returns 3679081200000.

So after dividing by (24*60*60*1000), I get 42582 and 42581.9 on Android 19 & 23 respectively.

The following code works on both Android 19 & 23.

```
public static int DateToInt(String date) {
    int dateInInteger = 693595;
    SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date startDate = null;
    Date presentDate = null;

    try {
        startDate = dfDate.parse("01/01/1900");
        presentDate = dfDate.parse(date);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    double diff = presentDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    double diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    return dateInInteger + (int) Math.ceil(diffDays);
}
```